# Create js webpack config

Tags: webpack

How to create a webpack configuration file for js files correctly?

[image]

Me need create webpack config file for folder src/Components/Auth/js/modules (Inside folder have JS file)

Answer (score -1):

***[From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack)***

> Webpack is an open-source JavaScript module bundler. Its main purpose
>   is to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

---

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```

---

***create webpack.config.js file in root of your project direcotry***

***webpack.config.js***

```
const path = require('path') // This is common.js

console.log('*** webpack started loading. ***');

/*
   webpack config object takes two parameters.
   1. entry: firstFile which need to be loaded.
   2. output:
      -path: directory name so it can store fully minified version of .js 
             files. need to specifiy fully qualified path.
      -filename: file name of minified file.
*/
  const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
}

console.log('*** webpack loading completed. ***');

module.exports = config; // this is common.js
```

***Now to run from your terminal type `'webpack'`***

***For more info below is the `package.json` file.***

```
{
  "name": "hello_webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.19.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

***[For Basic Example click here](https://github.com/AshokICreate/webpack/tree/master/js_modules)***